# What is wrong with my SAML Response? (Office365 SSO)

Tags: single-sign-on, microsoft-office-365, federated

I have been trying to federate an Office365 domain for some time now with no luck. I have gotten to the point in which I receive a request and am able to generate a response based off that, but don't know if the response it correct. I am getting this error:

> ## Sorry, but we're having trouble signing you in
>
> You can't use an organizational account to sign in to this site. Please make sure that you typed the web site address correctly. If you still have trouble, you might want to contact your admin.

Here are my SAML request & responses (with sensitive info removed)

### Request

```
<samlp:AuthnRequest
xmlns:samlp='urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol'
xmlns:saml='urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion'
ID='_1ae9c30e-8767-44e4-8221-ecd18d55e1c0'
IssueInstant='2015-03-09T20:46:12Z'
Version='2.0'
AssertionConsumerServiceIndex='0'>
 <saml:Issuer>
  urn:federation:MicrosoftOnline
 </saml:Issuer>
 <samlp:NameIDPolicy
 Format='urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent'/>
</samlp:AuthnRequest>
```

### Response

```
<samlp:Response
Destination='https://login.microsoftonline.com/login.srf'
ID='AD5D2AFFA557338C737661EA4746DE1F5DEB0575C7'
InResponseTo='_1ae9c30e-8767-44e4-8221-ecd18d55e1c0'
IssueInstant='2015-03-09T20:46:12Z' Version='2.0'
xmlns:saml='urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion'
xmlns:samlp='urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol'>
 <saml:Issuer>
   http://self.clearlogin.com/ 
 </saml:Issuer>
 <samlp:Status>
  <samlp:StatusCode Value='urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success'/>
 </samlp:Status>
 <saml:Assertion ID='D1B7C4F18C08B5E2A0B4811121FF8FC18E5CE2C305'
 IssueInstant='2015-03-09T20:46:12Z'
 Version='2.0'
 xmlns:saml='urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion'>
  <saml:Issuer>
    http://self.clearlogin.com/ 
  </saml:Issuer>
  <ds:Signature xmlns:ds='http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#'>
   <ds:SignedInfo xmlns:ds='http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#'>
    <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm='http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#'/>
    <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm='http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha1'/>
    <ds:Reference URI='#D1B7C4F18C08B5E2A0B4811121FF8FC18E5CE2C305'>
     <ds:Transforms>
      <ds:Transform Algorithm='http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature'/>
      <ds:Transform Algorithm='http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#'/>
     </ds:Transforms>
     <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm='http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha1'/>
     <ds:DigestValue>
      [REDACTED]
     </ds:DigestValue>
    </ds:Reference>
   </ds:SignedInfo>
   <ds:SignatureValue>
    [REDACTED]
   </ds:SignatureValue>
   <ds:KeyInfo>
    <ds:X509Data>
     <ds:X509Certificate>
      [REDACTED]
     </ds:X509Certificate>
    </ds:X509Data>
   </ds:KeyInfo>
  </ds:Signature>
  <saml:Subject>
   <saml:NameID
   Format='urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent'
   NameQualifier='http://self.clearlogin.com'
   SPNameQualifier='urn:federation:MicrosoftOnline'>
    ABCDEG1234567890 
   </saml:NameID>
   <saml:SubjectConfirmation
   Method='urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer'>
    <saml:SubjectConfirmationData
    InResponseTo='_1ae9c30e-8767-44e4-8221-ecd18d55e1c0'
    NotOnOrAfter='2015-03-09T21:06:12Z'
    Recipient='https://login.microsoftonline.com/login.srf'/>
   </saml:SubjectConfirmation>
  </saml:Subject>
  <saml:Conditions
  NotBefore='2015-03-09T20:46:12Z'
  NotOnOrAfter='2015-03-09T21:06:12Z'>
   <saml:AudienceRestriction>
    <saml:Audience>
      urn:federation:MicrosoftOnline 
    </saml:Audience>
   </saml:AudienceRestriction>
  </saml:Conditions>
  <saml:AuthnStatement AuthnInstant='2015-03-09T20:46:12Z'>
   <saml:AuthnContext>
    <saml:AuthnContextClassRef>
      urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Password 
    </saml:AuthnContextClassRef>
   </saml:AuthnContext>
  </saml:AuthnStatement>
  <saml:AttributeStatement>
   <saml:Attribute Name='IDPEmail'>
    <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type='xs:string'
    xmlns:xs='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'
    xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'>
     [REDACTED]
    </saml:AttributeValue>
   </saml:Attribute>
  </saml:AttributeStatement>
 </saml:Assertion>
</samlp:Response>
```

### idP

We are using a third party idP (ourselves) for creating the SAML response. We are **NOT** using ADFS.

### Set-MsolDomainAuthentication

```
Import-Module MSOnline
$idpSub = Read-Host 'Please enter the idP subdomain on clearlogin.com: '
$passiveLogin = "https://"+idpSub+".clearlogin-stage.com/apps/office365/login"
$logout = "https://"+$idpSub+".clearlogin-stage.com/apps/logout"
$issuer = "https://"+$idpSub+".clearlogin-stage.com/"
$certPath = C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop
$cert = New-Object
  System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2($certPath)
$certData = [system.convert]::tobase64string($cert.rawdata)
$msdomain = Read-Host 'Please enter your Office365 domain.'
Set-MsolDomainAuthentication
  -Authentication Federated
  -DomainName $msdomain
  -FederationBrandName $msdomain
  -IssuerUri $issuer
  -LogOffUri $logout
  -PassiveLogOnUri $passiveLogin
  -SigningCertificate $certData
  -PreferredAuthenticationProtocol Samlp
```

### EDIT 1:

Added some more info and my Set-MsolDomainAuthentication command.

Comment: Did you add the domain in question into Office365? Did you test your ADFS deployment? Have you converted your domain in Office365 to Federated? Please provide details.

Comment: I did add the domain and verify it. I do not use ADFS as I am using a third party idP. I have converted my domain using the Set-MsolDomainAuthenticate method. I should have put that info to begin with and I will post the details of that in there now! Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you can try referring to something similar as this link:
https://blogs.oracle.com/dcarru/entry/integrating_office_365_with_oif1
to try troubleshoot the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issues seemed to lay in a few places. The cert had the wrong issuer encoded, and the digest values were wrong.